# While trying to start the server, system throws Client is not a constructor error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

While starting the server via `node server.js` from command line, system throws following error:

`const pool = new Client({`
^
`TypeError: Client is not a constructor at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Max\study\blogs\src\db\dbConfig.js:3:14)`
Could someone please advise how to fix this error ?

**db/dbConfig.js**

```
const Client = require("pg");

const pool = new Client({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "postgres",
  port: 5432,
  password: "some_password",
  database: "blogs",
});


pool.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = pool;
```

src/server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const db = require("./db/dbConfig");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer  = require('multer')
var path = require('path');
const moment = require('moment');

const app = express();

  
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong import statement. Instead of

```
const Client = require("pg");
```

You should use

```
const { Client } = require("pg");
```

Here's the corrected code for `db/dbConfig.js`:

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const pool = new Client({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "postgres",
  port: 5432,
  password: "some_password",
  database: "blogs",
});

pool.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply, accepted and upvoted